# How to use subprocess.run to echo (bash) inside another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, subprocess

I am learning python and decide to write this script but for any reason the row with the echo doesn't work.
Can somebody explain to me why?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

import sys
import subprocess

if len(sys.argv) == 1 : 
    sys.exit()

file_name = sys.argv[1] + '.py'
res = subprocess.run(['touch', file_name])
res = subprocess.run(['chmod', '744', file_name])
res = subprocess.run(['chown', 'user', file_name])
res = subprocess.run(['echo', '\'#!/usr/bin/env python3.5\'', '>>', file_name])
```

Thanks.

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: The ``>>`` is a shell pipe symbol, not an argument to ``echo``. Is there any reason why you try to use externals programs as one would do with a shell, instead of using Python's own features for that? E.g. ``open`` to touch and write to the file, and ``os.chmod`` and ``os.chown``?

Comment: @NicoHaase The script works fine just the last line doesn't work.
I could create the file, change the permission,change the user.. but couldn't add the shebang.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I didn't use the os.system because in the documentation is written: 

The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. This module intends to replace several older modules and functions:

os.system
os.spawn*

Comment: I'm not asking about ``os.system``, which is just another means to spawn a child process. I'm asking why you are using child processes at all, seeing how Python can do all that by itself – namely via ``open``, ``os.chmod``, and ``os.chown``.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem? Which return code is given? Have you tried whether that execution returns something on the shell?

Comment: BTW, why are you **appending** your text to the file, when that text is clearly intended to be the only contents the file has? (Similarly, there's no reason at all to use `touch`; just put the step creating contents *first*, and that'll implicitly create the file).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Presumably the `touch` first is because they want to be sure the permissions and ownership are correct before putting anything in the file. They don't need to append even so (`>` would truncate but still modify the original file without messing with permissions), but it can be reasonable to force creation, update permissions, then insert the data once it's "safe" (though as noted, it's even better to just do this from Python, where you can hold the open handle while fixing permissions, and then write afterwards, removing race conditions).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Because I didn't understand the functionality of both, os and child process.

Comment: @AbyW _Because I didn't understand the functionality of both, os and child process._ What do you mean? Doesn't that just reinforce the point MisterMiyagi made?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I use touch to create files because this was the  "way" that somebody teach me to create files, and yes, I could just echo "some text" > somefile.py

Comment: Or just `>somefile.py`, which on its own empties the file (whereas `touch` leaves the file there with its existing contents if it isn't empty when you start).

Comment: @AMC yes!! I am a php/js dev, I start to write python 5 minutes ago.. :-)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy again you are right.
A beutiful day to learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>>` is a shell operator; to use it, you'd need to pass a `str` to `run` instead of a sequence of arguments, and pass `shell=True` to make it execute in a subshell, e.g. [using `shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) to make it not completely impossibly unstable/insecure:

```
res = subprocess.run(f'echo \'#!/usr/bin/env python3.5\' >> {shlex.quote(file_name)}', shell=True)
```

That said, **don't do any of that**. You don't need to use subprocesses for *any* of this, as Python built-ins will do the same work, and substantially faster than using subprocesses:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    os.chmod(f.fileno(), 0o744)
    shutil.chown(f.fileno(), 'user')
    f.write('#!/usr/bin/env python3.5\n')
```

Comment: Why `shell=True`, and not `stdout=open(...)`? Less to go wrong if used carelessly (someone leaving out the `shlex.quote()`s with `shell=True` can make a very big mess).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Because it's wrong to use `subprocess` for this either way, so it hardly matters which wrong solution to show? :-) I was showing how they could do what they were attempting with shell metacharacters, then following up with "But never do that". Using `open` without `shell=True` is safer, but using `echo` subprocesses at all is weird, when it's always going to be easier to write to the file directly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks a lot... got it.
I have writing python like 10 minutes ;-) so...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, man

Answer (score 1):

`>>file` is an instruction *to your shell* to redirect stdout to `file`. When you use `subprocess` without `shell=True`, there is no shell at all, so you need to do that redirection yourself with the `stdout=` argument:

```
res = subprocess.run(['echo', '#!/usr/bin/env python3.5'], stdout=open(file_name, 'a'))
```

You'll notice that I also took out the extra `\'`s from your `echo`. That's because those strings are *also* instructions to the shell (telling it not to change any string contents); not having any shell, those instructions are no longer needed.

---

<sub>*Of course, don't ever do any of this; just write to the file in native Python.*</sub>

Comment: While it's likely wholly safe here (since Python itself never writes to it, so Python buffers aren't an issue), I get uneasy when I see file handles opened for write that aren't controlled by a `with` statement... Too easy to have buffers unflushed, handles left open until a garbage collection (on non-CPython interpreters, or CPython if a reference cycle is accidentally established), etc.